# Neo4j: How to get mutual nodes for list of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have this cypher code:

```
MATCH path = (me:Person {uuid: '{my_id}'})-[:friendship*2]->(p:Person)-[:courses]->(c:Course)
WHERE p.uuid<>'{my_id}'
RETURN distinct(c) as courses
```

This code return all courses of every person in a *2 relationship. But how can I get only similar courses for these Persons?

Fox example:
Person1 have: Course1, Course2, Course3.

Person2 have: Course2, Course3, Course4

My code will return `[Course1, Course2, Course3, Course4]`, but I need `[Course2, Course3]` (only mutual)

Thanks for answers.

Update 1:
Here is my version:

```
MATCH (me:Person {uuid: '{my_id}'})-[:friendship*2]->(p:Person)-[cr:courses]->(c:Course)
WITH collect(p) as persons, collect(cr) as courses_rel, g, collect(c) as courses
WHERE p.uuid<>'{my_id}' and all(rel in courses_rel WHERE all(person in persons WHERE startNode(rel) = person ))
RETURN courses
```

this code work, but return wrong data without filtering

Update 2:
[image: Here is sccreenshot]

I need to get 3 courses: `Ackerman, 27 Pines Golf Course, 18 Mile Creek Golf`

Comment: So it should not return anything in case there are no common courses among all the *r relationships?

Comment: yes, I need just common courses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, find all the distinct persons at level 2 and all the distinct courses they have. Pass these values to the next part of the query using `WITH`.

Then for each of these courses check if `all` the people have it or not.

```
MATCH path = (me:Person {uuid: '{my_id}'})-[:friendship*2]->(p:Person)-[:courses]->(c:Course)
WHERE p.uuid<>'{my_id}'
WITH collect(distinct(c)) as courses, collect(distinct(p)) as persons
MATCH (c:Course)
WHERE c in courses and all(p in persons where (p)-[:courses]->(c))
RETURN c as courses
```

**EDIT:**
In case you need courses that have been added by at least two friends, then find the count of persons for each course and filter out.

```
MATCH path = (me:Person {uuid: '{my_id}'})-[:friendship*2]->(p:Person)-[:courses]->(c:Course)
WHERE p.uuid<>'{my_id}'
WITH course, collect(distinct(p)) as persons
WHERE size(persons) >= 2
RETURN collect(course) as courses
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!, it works) My code was similar, but it didn't work :( .

Comment: Unfortunately this code doesn't work for me either. If I have two friends and they have 2 common clubs, then this works, But if I have a second pair of friends: Friend 3 and Friend 4, and they have completely different clubs in common, then this code will return an empty list, because the `WHERE c in courses and all(p in persons where (p)-[:courses]->(c))` code will return only those courses that EVERY friend has, and I just need clubs that have been added by at least two friends. Any ideas?

Comment: Rajendra Kadam, I've added screenshot

Comment: I thought common among all friends

Answer (score 0):

You also need to match your courses then. You can reuse the same variable to only get the mutual courses:

```
MATCH (c:Course)<-[:courses]-(me:Person {uuid: '{my_id}'})-[:friendship*2]->(p:Person)-[:courses]->(c)
WHERE p.uuid<>'{my_id}'
RETURN distinct(c) as courses
```